# binding attributes in vuejs component

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I am trying to use the last version of vuejs with Laravel 5.3 ! The idea I am trying to fulfill is make a component foreach user. So that I have all users listed and foreach one there is a button "edit" , when I click this button I should see the form to update this user.
So this is how I defined the component :

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '.view-wrap',
  components: {
    user-view: {
      template: '#user-view',
      props: ['user']
    }
  },
  data: {
    users: <?php echo json_encode($users); ?>,
  },
  methods: {
    showForm: function(number){
      $('div.update-user-'+number).css({'display':'block'});
      },

    getClassName: function (index) {
      return "update-user-"+index;
    },

    getUpdateUrl: function(id){
      return '/users/update/'+id;
    },
  }         
});
```

This is the template for the "user-view" which take a class name "updateClass" which contains the id of every user (for show/hide purposes), an "updateUrl" which is the url to update the user to bind it with each form action and finally the object user :

```
<template id="user-view">
  <div>
     <div class="updateclass">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="PUT" action="updateUrl">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label for="name"> Name </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" :value="user.name">
          </li>
          <li>
            {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'button-green smaller right']) !!}                  
          </li>
        </ul>
    {!! Form::close() !!}  
</div>
```

and This is finally how I call the template :

```
<user-view v-for="user in users" :updateclass="getClassName(user.id)" :user="user"  :updateUrl="getUpdateUrl(user.id)"></user-view>
```

The issue then : it seems that for example [class="updateclass"] doesn't change the value of updateclass with the result of getClassName(user.id) as defined in template call that is binded to. When I try it with [:class="updateclass"] in the template I get : Property or method "updateclass" is not defined on the instance ...

and the same thing applies to all other binded attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using to assign a class dynamically is wrong. from the `getClassName` method you have to return a object having className like this : `{"className: true}` , like following

```
getClassName: function (index) {
      var tmp = {}
      var className = 'update-user-'+index
      tmp[className] = true
      return tmp
    }
```

Than you can assign it like following as is in [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax):

```
<div :class="updateclass"></div>
```

Comment: this line    return { "update-user-"+index: true}   generates : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +